# Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server using Clojure

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, clojure

I am trying to connect to Microsoft SQl Server 2008 database using windows authentication.
I have downloaded the JDBC driver for MS SQL Server and added that to my CLASSPATH.

Below is my clojure code. No matter what I do I get java.sql.SQLException :  No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

```
(ns Test)
(def db {:classname "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"
               :subprotocol "sqlserver"
               :subname "server_name"
               :DatabaseName "database_name"
               :integratedSecurity true
})

(use 'clojure.contrib.sql)
(with-connection db 
      (with-query-results rs ["SELECT * FROM sys.objects"] (prn rs)))
```

I have verified that I have access on database , my classpath is correct , I have the correct JDBC version downloaded . Can someone help me out here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens is that code is translated to Java?

Comment: Just add that to use with ```:integratedSecurity true``` on Windows one has to add *sqljdbc_auth.dll* to CLASSPATH (for example into /Resources folder) and Path Env

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution

```clj
(use 'clojure.contrib.sql)
    (def db {:classname "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
                   :subprotocol "sqlserver"
                   :subname "//server-name:port;database=database-name;user=sql-authentication-user-name;password=password"
    })

    ;Add Classpath to your C:\Program Files\Java\JDBC\sqljdbc_3.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar
    ;Below code demos how to execute a simple sql select query and print it to console
    ;This query will print all the user tables in your MS SQL Server Database
    (with-connection db 
          (with-query-results rs ["select * from sys.objects  where type = 'U'"] 
               (doseq [row rs] (println (:name row)))
    ))
```

Also updated the wiki http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/JDBC_Examples#Microsoft_SQL_Server

Hopefully this will help someone

Comment: Note that clojure.contrib.sql has been discontinued (as of mid-2011) and replaced by clojure.java.jdbc, as shown in Alexey's answer.

Comment: shouldn't this mean "add C:\Program Files\Java\JDBC\sqljdbc_3.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar to your CLASSPATH"?

Answer (score 18):

## Connecting to the database

In the later software versions (Clojure 1.6+, Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server) the code posted by Ash works only with these modifications. I've also updated it according to my current knowledge of Clojure code styling guidelines.

```clj
(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc])
;; you can optionally specify :host and :port to override the defaults
;; of "127.0.0.1" and 1433 respectively:
(def db-spec {:dbtype "mssql"
              :dbname "database-name"
              :user "sql-authentication-user-name"
              :password "password"})

(let [rows (jdbc/query db-spec
                       ["select * from sys.objects  where type = 'U'"])]
  (doseq [row rows] (println (:name row)))))
```

In the case of having multiple SQL Server instances on the same machine, you can specify the instance name as part of the `:host` like this (this example is for the default instance name of SQL Server Express on the same machine):

```
:host "localhost\\sqlexpress"
```

## Configuring Leiningen

To make Leiningen work properly with Microsoft JDBC Driver, merge the following with defproject in project.clj:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.6.1"]
               [com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc "6.3.6.jre8-preview"]]
```

Comment: I needed to manually add my classpath into `project.clj` like so: `:resource-paths ["C:/Program Files/Java/JDBC/sqljdbc_4.1/enu/sqljdbc41.jar"]`

Comment: Additional note that the leading `//` in `:subname` is important. Without it the JDBC connection string breaks in a confusing way.

Comment: @jocull Thanks for emphasizing the importance of `//` in `:subname`. Regarding the project. Somehow in my case it was working without adding classpath manually.

Comment: I used [lein-localrepo](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo) which seems less intrusive.

Comment: @SteffenRoller thank you, I've tried it and updated the answer. It really seems to be an easier option for most cases.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how `:dbtype` / `:dbname` can make things much simpler -- you don't need the classname, subprotocol, or subname -- as well as removing the unnecessary `with-db-connection` wrapper (you only need that if you want to run multiple queries in a single connection).

Comment: The driver is now available from Maven at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc

Comment: I had to add `:port`. The default port being used was 1433 whereas my mssql server default port is 4134.

Answer (score 2):

the prior answers are all correct and work just fine. However, the post is quite old and there are better options out there. Hence I thought it would make sense to update the post for the people searching for a solution (as I was).

It turns out that `clojure.java.jdbc` *is "Stable" (no longer "Active"). It has effectively been superseded by* `seancorfield/next.jdbc`.

Using `next.jdbc` is rather straightforward and more information can be found in the project page https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc:

### Code

```
(require '[next.jdbc :as jdbc])
(def db {:dbtype "mssql"
         :dbname "database-name"
         :host "host" ;;optional
         :port "port" ;;optional
         :user "sql-authentication-user-name"
         :password "password"})
(def con (jdbc/get-connection db))
(jdbc/execute! con ["select * from sys.objects  where type = 'U'"])
```

### Leiningen configuration

```
:dependencies [[seancorfield/next.jdbc "1.0.10"]]
               [com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc "7.4.1.jre11"]]
```

**Note:** Download the mssql-jdbc driver that suits your jre version and place it in the resources folder of your leiningen project or add the path to the driver in the `:dependencies [<path-here>]` in your project.clj